# Unformatted Textarea with Very Basic Text Styling

Tags: custom-fields, wysiwyg

What's the best way to have an unformatted textarea field (meaning no `<p>` or `<br>` tags), but still allow the client to make text bold, italic, or add a link?

I often have to put content into a specific element (`<p class="summary">`, for example), so it can't be wrapped in its own `<p>` tags. And often for styling purposes the content can't have line breaks. But the content can still have bold or italic text or contain a link. Example:

> This is an example of some summary text. **Text can be bold**, or it can be *emphasized*, and it can even [contain a link](http://google.com) because these are all inline changes that don't affect layout.

Is there any client-friendly way (read: no html tags) to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you: Create a very minimal Wygwam config, with just Bold, Italics, and Link options.

Then in your template, wrap the Wygwam tag with something like Low Replace to remove all <p>, </p>, <br>, and <br />

Comment: @Dylan That's certainly an option, I just wish I didn't have to add the extra overhead of a plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of suggestions:

- have you looked into using Textile or Markdown for your textarea?
- use a div.summary instead of a p
- CE String has [methods](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-string/user-guide/custom_methods) to strip out tags from html, check  `remove_tags` or `remove_tags_except` *(I use this a lot personally - lots of other useful methods too in this plugin)*
- Wygwam has a [text-only mode](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/templating/field.html#text-only-mode) that can be useful.

Comment: I would second what erwinheiser has suggested. EllisLab have just added Markdown parsing to the new [2.7 release](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-2.7.0-released) and that's sounds like a good fit for what you need.

Comment: @Steve_Holland ORLY? I didn't know they support Markdown now. That sounds pretty good. Still not as client-friendly as a WYSIWYG, but better than raw HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in [**html formatting buttons**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/default_html_buttons.html) in EE, which can be enabled on a Textarea field. This would meet your requirement of no `br` or `p` tags without the need of a plugin to strip them out.

When the user clicks a formatting button the correct html is applied automatically, but it does leave the tags exposed (not a wysiwyg).

[image]